# What is this weird overlay shown on my SettingsPane?

Tags: macos, swiftui

Here's my code, I don't get why this results in this transparent overlay when I move focus to the `Text` or `SecureField` components

```
struct SettingsPane: View {
    
    // MARK: View state
    @State private var isSecured: Bool = true
    @State private var showApiKeyPopover: Bool = false

    // MARK: Preference Storage
    @AppStorage("preference_showWorkboard") var showWorkboard = true
    @AppStorage("preference_userName") var userName = ""
    @AppStorage("preference_jiraApiKey") var jiraApiKey = ""
    
    // MARK: View dimensions
    var frameWidth:CGFloat = 200
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Credentials")) {
                TextField("User", text: $userName)
                    .textContentType(.username)
                    .frame(width: frameWidth)
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Group {
                        if isSecured {
                            SecureField("Jira API Key", text: $jiraApiKey)
                                .textContentType(.password)
                                .frame(width: frameWidth)
                                .lineLimit(1)
                        } else {
                            TextField("Jira API Key", text: $jiraApiKey)
                                .textContentType(.password)
                                .frame(width: frameWidth)
                                .lineLimit(1)
                        }
                    }.popover(isPresented: $showApiKeyPopover) {
                        Text("To get an API key visit your Jira profile.\nClick 'Personal Access Tokens' and create one named 'Firehose' and add it to this field")
                            .padding()
                    }

                    Button(action: {
                        isSecured.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: self.isSecured ? "eye.slash" : "eye")
                            .accentColor(.gray)
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                    Button(action: {
                        showApiKeyPopover.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle.fill")
                            .accentColor(.gray)
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                }
                Divider()
                Section(header: Text("Features")) {
                    Toggle("Show Workboard", isOn: $showWorkboard)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(minWidth: 400, maxWidth: 400)
    }
}
```

[image: Strange overlay on Settings pane]

Answer (score 1):

It works fine with me (macOS 13.0, Xcode 14.1). I get this ...
Could it be some password utility interfering?

[image]

Comment: hmm, that's a good lead.  I'm on macOS 12.6 and Xcode 14.1.  I use Keepass which I quit to see if it was that but even with Keepass not running I get the same result.  I don't have any other password managers installed.  So unless it's macOS itself...